# drawing scatterplot 3D in r

Tags: r, plot, visualization, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I would like to visualize my data in a scatterplot3d

On my X and Y axis, I would like the same lables. Something like this:

```
x<-c("A","B","C","D")
y<-c("A","B","C","D")
```

on the Z axis, I would like to show the comparision between lables in X and Y

```
A with A
A with B
A with c
A with D
B with B
B with C
B with D
C with C
C with D
D with D

#altogether 10 values in Z
z<-c(0.25, 0.7, 0.35, 1.14, 0.85, 0.36, 0.69, 0.73, 0.023, 0.85)
```

Now I want to draw all of of these infos on  `scatterplot3d`. How can I implement this concept on scatterplot3d?

Comment: There 16 combinations (not 10) between `x` and `y`, so I don't understand what you asking for

Comment: `A with B`is same with `B with A`. I have esited my post

Comment: Why -1? then I can update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot points, you need to match triplets of `(x,y,z)` values. You can create `x` and `y` values matching the positions in `z` with

```
xx <- factor(rep(x, 4:1), levels=x)
yy <- factor(unlist(sapply(1:4, function(i) y[i:4])), levels=y)
```

Then you can draw the plot with

```
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(xx,yy,z, 
    x.ticklabs=c("",x,""), y.ticklabs=c("",y,""), 
    type="h", lwd=2,
    xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5))
```

to get

[image]

But honestly this doesn't seem like a particularly effective visualization.