# How do you plot a 3d scatterplot with multiple facets?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a 3d scatterplot (let's use [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721271/drawing-scatterplot-3d-in-r) as an example), but as a grid with multiple 3D scatterplots on the same page based on a categorical factor. I see how many people can do this with, for example, [boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o9ZS.png), but have no idea how to do so with a 3-d scatterplot. Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `cloud` function in the `lattice` package, although it probably doesn't offer as much easy fine-scale control as `scatterplot3d`- or `rgl`-based plots:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(1000),y=runif(1000),z=runif(1000),
  f=factor(sample(1:10,replace=TRUE,size=1000)))
library("lattice")
cloud(z~x*y|f,data=d)
```